# How to implement a Pagination for dynamic data from a HTTP-Table on Angular

Tags: binding, paginator

How i can bind a Paginator, that changes the Items per Page when i change the Number f.e. from 10 to 5. Now i can change the number of the paginator, but the table and the shown data are the same.

**this is my HTML-Component**

```
 <div class="example-container">
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource"  class="example-table"
 matSort >....

<mat-paginator [length]="resultsLength"
               [pageSize]="pageSize"
               [pageSizeOptions]="pageSizeOptions"
                showFirstLastButtons
               (page) ="pageEvent = $event">
</mat-paginator>
```

**And this is my Typescript-File**

```
export class TableHttpExample implements AfterViewInit , OnInit {...

  displayedColumns: string[] = ['CheckboxA','UserName','name', 'vorname', 'email', 'Strasse', 'PLZ'];
  exampleDatabase: ExampleHttpDatabase | null;
  data: User[] = [];
  dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<User>(data);
  resultsLength = null;
  isLoadingResults = true;
  checkbox_list =[];
  isRateLimitReached = false;
  user: User;
  pageSize = 10;
  pageSizeOptions: number[] = [5, 10, 25, 100];
  pageEvent: PageEvent;


   ...

   ngOnInit() {
     this._dataService.getUsers().subscribe((Users: User[]) => this.loadUsers(Users));
     this.checkbox_list = [User];
     this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
     this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
    };


    loadUsers(Users) {
      this.dataSource = Users;
      this.resultsLength = Users.length;
      this.pageSize = Users.length;
      this.isLoadingResults = false;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

First in ngOnInit() slice data to whatever number you want as

```
this.dataSource.filteredData.slice(0, pageSize);
```

then you should pass $event to function.

```
<mat-paginator [pageSize]="pageSize" [length]="length" (page)="pageEvent = OnPageChange($event)" [pageSizeOptions]="pageSizeOptions"></mat-paginator>

  OnPageChange(event: PageEvent) {
    let startIndex = event.pageIndex * event.pageSize;
    let endIndex = startIndex + event.pageSize;
    this.dataSource.filteredData.slice(startIndex, endIndex);
  }
```